# how to fix this code (conversion binary to decimal with char in c)?

Tags: c, binary

why this code don't work? (i want To convert a number from binary to decimal)
there is a problem with pointer? or multiplication(char*int)

```
char cara[100];
char *t=cara;
int i=0;
int sum=0;
int j=0;
int m;

printf("entrer a binary number\n");
scanf("%s",&cara);
while(*t!="\0")
{
    j++;
    m=j-1;
}


for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    cara[i]=cara[i]*pow(2,m);
    m--;
}
int k;
for(k=0;k<j;k++)
{
    sum=sum+cara[i];
}
printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: `while(*t!="\0")` what did your compiler say?

Comment: the compiler say nothing

Comment: OT: Using `pow` for this really unnecessary.

Comment: @mohamedbenhaddou Then recompile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: `cara[i]=cara[i]*pow(2,m);` is wrong

Comment: the code is compiled without errors and also without result

Comment: "cara[i]=cara[i]*pow(2,m); is wrong " why this is wrong??

Comment: @mohamedbenhaddou the code you posted here is not the code you compiled. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean with _DON'T WORK_ ???  Please, post things that can be tested.  You will not be flamed if you explain what does it mean _DON'T WORK_.

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bug is here:

```
while(*t!="\0")
```

You have to use single quotes for characters - like `while(*t!='\0')`. To make it simpler you can just write `while(*t)`.

Besides that problem also notice that you **never update** `t`. You need to add `++t;` inside the loop.

The second bug is here:

```
cara[i]=cara[i]*pow(2,m);
```

Characters `'0'` and `'1'` do **not** have integer values zero and one so the calculation is wrong. The character `'0'` has integer value 48 and character `'1'` has integer value 49 (see https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) so the result will be completely wrong.

To get the calculation more correct you need:

```
cara[i] = (cara[i] - '0') * pow(2,m);
```

However, it is **a bad idea** to save these intermediate results back in a `char`. A `char` can't hold values higher than 127 (or 255 if `char` is unsigned) so you'll soon have an integer overflow.

In general there is no need for saving these intermediate result and there is no need for `pow` as you can simply multiply by 2 for each binary digit.

Try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *bin_str = "11001";
    unsigned result = 0;
    while (*bin_str)
    {
        result *= 2;
        result += *bin_str == '1' ? 1 : 0;
        ++bin_str;
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help and your explanations.

Comment: and this is the new code:                                                                                                                 #include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char cara[100];
char *t=cara;
int i=0;
int sum=0;
int j=0;
int m;

printf("entrer a binary number\n");
scanf("%s",&cara);
while(*t)
{ ++t;
    j++;
    m=j-1;
}


for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
   cara[i] = (cara[i] - '0') * pow(2,m);
    m--;
}
int k;
for(k=0;k<j;k++)
{
    sum=sum+cara[k];
}
printf("%d",sum);

    }